# MySQL - Select row with column + X > column

Tags: mysql

We have a database for patients that shows the details of their various visits to our office, such as their weight during that visit.  I want to generate a report that returns the visit (a row from the table) based on the difference between the date of that visit and the patient's first visit being the largest value possible but not exceeding X number of days.

That's confusing, so let me try an example.  Let's say I have the following table called `patient_visits`:

```
visit_id | created             | patient_id | weight
---------+---------------------+------------+-------
       1 | 2006-08-08 09:00:05 |         10 |    180
       2 | 2006-08-15 09:01:03 |         10 |    178
       3 | 2006-08-22 09:05:43 |         10 |    177
       4 | 2006-08-29 08:54:38 |         10 |    176
       5 | 2006-09-05 08:57:41 |         10 |    174
       6 | 2006-09-12 09:02:15 |         10 |    173
```

In my query, if I were wanting to run this report for "30 days", I would want to return the row where `visit_id = 5`, because it's 28 days into the future, and the next row is 35 days into the future, which is too much.

I've tried a variety of things, such as joining the table to itself, or creating a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to try to return the max value of `created` WHERE it is equal to or less than `created + 30 days`, but I seem to be at a loss at this point.  As a last resort, I can just pull all of the data into a PHP array and build some logic there, but I'd really rather not.

The bigger picture is this: The database has about 5,000 patients, each with any number of office visits.  I want to build the report to tell me what the average wait loss has been for all patients combined when going from their first visit to X days out (that is, X days from each individual patient's first visit, not an arbitrary X-day period).  I'm hoping that if I can get the above resolved, I'll be able to work the rest out.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: for each patient_id one should take the *earliest* visit (let's call it *anchor*), then find another visit that is *the most distant* from anchor but no more than X days from the anchor. All other visits (that is those more close to anchor and those above X days) should be discarded. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date of the first and next visit using query like this (Note that this doesn't has correct syntax for date comparing and it is just an schema of the query):

```
select
    first_visits.patient_id,
    first_visits.date first_date,
    max(next_visit.created) next_date
from (
    select patient_id, min(created) as "date"
    from patient_visits
    group by patient_id
) as first_visits
inner join patient_visits next_visit
  on (next_visit.patient_id = first_visits.patient_id 
      and next_visit.created between first_visits.created and first_visits.created + 30 days)
group by first_visits.patient_id, first_visits.date
```

So basically you need to find start date using grouping by `patient_id` and then join `patient_visits` and find max date that is within the 30 days window.

Then you can join the result to `patient_visits` to get start and end weights and calculate the loss.

Comment: This seems to be going in the right direction. I was able to change a few things above to make it an executable query and it does return the appropriate dates, and in 1.02 seconds. I'm having two problems with the joins though. The first is speed.. it takes 64 seconds to execute. The second is that I can't figure out how to join the next visit.. I can't join a table `ON max(next_visit.created)` or `ON next_date`.